# Facebook API graph leads retrieving

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have a couple of forms for potential clients, which I have to retrieve through the GRAPH API of Facebook.
I have followed exactly the documentation that appears in this link `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api /guides/lead-ads/retrieving/v2.10?locale=es_LA`

I already generated the permanent token with the necessary permissions and can read the information for a single user but not for others.

I already used the date filter using the operator and passing as parameters `LESS_THAN`, `GREATER_THAN` and `GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL`.

I would like to know why the others do not come out, and if possible, can it only show me the leads after it creates an app?

Comment: Looks like it might be an issue with the logic flow. Can you show what has been till now?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed your App for the different pages? That's FB-terminology for subscribing to the webhook events for leads retrieval. Until you install your app for those other pages, you won't receive the events.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/getting-started/webhooks-for-pages#install-app